# Using language model tool without any installation

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4, language-model

I know that there are some language model tools which are [IRSLM](http://hlt-mt.fbk.eu/technologies/irstlm), [MITLM](https://github.com/mitlm/mitlm), [SRILM](http://www-speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/) . All of them need to a installation to be able to create a language model etc.

However I need a language model tool which is not needed any installation and can be used offline.

And also there is a [lmtool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html) which can create a language model file using the website.

Is there any tool ?

Comment: You've got an answer to your question here: https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/09146466/?limit=25#5e2f/6bc5

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev thanks again